How to Invert X-Axis for Touchscreen Calibration on Linux (Ubuntu)
I'm encountering an issue with touchscreen calibration on a kiosk system I'm building. The setup consists of Linux Ubuntu with a JavaFX front end and a Python Flask back end. The problem is that touches on the left side of the screen are registered on the right side and vice versa, effectively creating a mirrored X-axis.
I've attempted various configurations using xinput and xinput_calibrator, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue. Here is a summary of what I've tried so far:
Adjusting the transformation matrix using xinput set-prop commands.
Using xinput_calibrator to recalibrate, but the calibration doesn't seem to stick.
Here's a sample of the xinput command I've been working with:
xinput set-prop "Device Name" "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 

Despite these efforts, the touch input remains inverted along the X-axis.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to correctly invert the X-axis for the touchscreen? Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You just used the identity matrix: If I write out your numbers as 3×3 matrix (row major), then 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 becomes
⎡ 1  0  0 ⎤
⎢ 0  1  0 ⎥,
⎣ 0  0  1 ⎦

which gets multiplied with a [x y 1] column vector (documentation), where these coordinates are normalized by the total device width (for x) or height (for y). So, inverting x is easy:
⎡a b c⎤   ⎡x⎤ ! ⎡1-x⎤
⎢d e f⎥ · ⎢y⎥ = ⎢ y ⎥
⎣g h i⎦   ⎣1⎦   ⎣ 1 ⎦

is quickly solved by hand ("the power of taking a sharp look") to
⎡a b c⎤   ⎡-1  0  1 ⎤
⎢d e f⎥ = ⎢ 0  1  0 ⎥,
⎣g h i⎦   ⎣ 0  0  1 ⎦

which "serializes" to -1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1.

Thank you a lot! I have to learn this calculation of the matrix :)
